# How to fetch a particular filename pattern from directory

Tags: c#, file, directory

I'm trying to fetch a particular filename from a directory. The code I've tried is as below

```
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(directoryPath);
FileInfo recentlyModLogFile = (from files in dirInfo.GetFiles("^Monarch_[0-9]{2}$") orderby files.LastWriteTime descending select files).First();
//Output : Error
```

List of file names (Input)

```
Monarch_05bridge  //Date modified 16-12-2021 20:41
Monarch_04bridge  //Date modified 16-12-2021 06:49
Monarch_04  //Date modified 16-12-2021 05:39
Monarch_02  //Date modified 16-12-2021 05:49
Monarch_02bridge  //Date modified 14-12-2021 19:34
Monarch_01  //Date modified 14-12-2021 09:08
```

Code should look for files whose filename starts with Monarch_ followed by 2 numeric digits  and then filter out the recently modified file

So the output should be `Monarch_02`

I also tried doing

```
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(directoryPath);
FileInfo recentlyModLogFile = (from files in dirInfo.GetFiles(Monarch_ + "*") orderby files.LastWriteTime descending select files).First();
//OUtput : Monarch_05bridge
```

Can someone help me to resolve  this issue.

Comment: The search pattern of [DirectoryInfo.GetFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles) supports ony `?` and `*` wildcards, no regex. Your second approach (use `GetFiles("Monarch_*)`) will work, you can then filter against a regex in addition.

Answer (score 2):

```csharp
string youngestFile = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath)
.Where(o => Regexp.Contains(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(o), "Monarch_\\d\\d"))
.OrderByDescending(o => File.GetLastWriteTime(o))
.FirstOrDefault();
```

This is a quick copy-and-paste from my project files. The Regexp.Contains() is one of the simple methods I wrote to do regexp comparisons.

Notice the Regular Expression I used allow `Monarch_02`, `Monarch_02Bridge` and `abcMonarch_09` all to be possible result. You can use `"^Monarch_\\d\\d$"`, if you want a strict rule.

Refer to [Regular Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference) for details.

```csharp
private static Match GetFirstMatch(string text, string pattern)
{
   Match match = Regex.Match(text, pattern, RegexOptions.None);
   return match;
}

public static Boolean Contains(string text, string pattern)
{
   return GetFirstMatch(text, pattern).Value != String.Empty;
}
```

Basically, use Directory.GetFiles(path) to get all the files, then use LINQ to apply conditions, order-bys and fetch the first result.

The [Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path?view=net-6.0), [Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory?view=net-6.0) and [File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=net-6.0) classes can help a lot when you are working around file system.

Comment: As of now this solution works, will test it for some time as per my scenario. Thanks for the input.